# Importing CSV and using Get-Hotfix to export to CSV

Tags: powershell

So, I'm having some difficulty with some code I'm trying to use to get hotfixes from a lot of computers (which are listed in a CSV file under the column "IP Address") and export that result to a csv. They each require a local computer account to log in (in the same CSV under the column "CPU Name"). I don't really care if it's one csv for the whole thing or a csv for each result. Here's the code so far:

```
$ipaddress = [What do I put here?]
$cpuname = [What do I put here?]
$OutputFile = 'MyFolder\Computer.csv'
$Username = '$cpuname\MyUsername' [Is this ok?]
$Password = 'MyPassword'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force

$SecureString = $pass
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString

$Computers = Import-CSV "C:\MyFolder\Computers.csv"

ForEach ($ipaddress in $Computers) {
    }

  try  

    { 
Get-HotFix -Credential $MySecureCreds -ipaddress $IPAddress | Select-Object PSComputerName,HotFixID,Description,InstalledBy,InstalledOn | export-csv $OutputFile
    } 

catch

    { 
Write-Warning "System Not reachable:$ipaddress"
    }
```

Am I close?

Comment: What happens when this code is run? Did it meet your requirements? If not, in what way did it not meet the requirements? See https://stackoverflow.com/help for information about how to ask.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's reading the IP address column correctly. It just says the system isn't reachable. How do I reference the "IP Address" column in $ipaddress and the "CPU Name" column in $cpuname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP Address and the Computer Name are coming from the CSV, so you don't need to statically define them.

Regarding the username, a couple things:

- You need to use double quotes to expand.
- Also you'll need to read the 'CPU Name' property one way to do this
  would be using a subexpression inside of the double quoted larger expression e.g. `"$($variable.property)more text"`. Or you could concatenate the string `$variable.property + 'more text'`
- Since `CPU Name` has a space in the column name you'll need to enclose that in quotes.
- Since the User name comes from the Computer name which comes from the
  CSV, defining the User name variable needs to be in the `foreach` loop.

The security practices in this script are questionable, but outside the scope of the question. e.g. Saving passwords in scripts, especially a local account with administrative privileges to a large number of networked machines that all have that same password...

```
$InputFile = 'C:\MyFolder\Input.csv'
$OutputFile = 'C:\MyFolder\Output.csv'
$Password = Read-Host | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Computers = Import-CSV $InputFile

$HotfixOutput = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    $Username = "$($Computer.'CPU Name')\MyUsername"
    $MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

    try { 
        Get-HotFix -Credential $MySecureCreds -ipaddress $Computer.'IP Address' | Select-Object PSComputerName, HotFixID, Description, InstalledBy, InstalledOn
    } 

    catch { 
        Write-Warning "System Not reachable: $($Computer.'IP Address')"
    }

}

$HotfixOutput | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation

Remove-Variable Password
Remove-Variable MySecureCreds
```

Comment: As to the security concerns, you're quite right. These are on a network but not on a domain (hence not being able to use SCCM or something else to get this information. I would do this by hand but it's like a total of a hundred systems and I don't really feel like entering the password that many times.

The password itself doesn't meet any sort of security requirements. They're not going to be around for much longer (hopefully).

Comment: Oh and also where do I put the password, in this scenario?

Comment: This code prompts you with the `Read-Host` and passes the input into `ConvertTo-SecureString` so that way at least it's not saved in the script. And the `Remove-Variable` make sure that the credentials aren't saved in memory