# Tweaking my Get-Hotfix code and making it more secure

Tags: powershell, credentials

After asking about the [Get Hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616507/importing-csv-and-using-get-hotfix-to-export-to-csv/) command I was working on, I tweaked the code enough to get it to work in my environment; however, I would like to make it more secure and handle error situations better. The existing code is really vague and it's not very easy to find out where failure points are without debugging.

Here's the code that I used:

```
$InputFile = 'C:\***\Computers.csv'
$Computers = Import-CSV $InputFile
$OutputFile = 'C:\***\Results.csv'
$Password = '***' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

$HotfixOutput = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    $Username = "$($Computer.CPUName)\***"
    $MySecureCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username,$Password)

    try { 
        Get-HotFix -Credential $MySecureCreds -ipaddress $Computer.IPAddress | Select-Object PSComputerName, HotFixID, Description, InstalledBy, InstalledOn
    } 

    catch { 
        Write-Warning "System Not reachable: $($Computer.IPAddress)"
    }

}

$HotfixOutput | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation

Remove-Variable Password
Remove-Variable MySecureCreds
```

Now, I want to do a few things to the code to make it more secure and maybe a bit quicker. My first thought is to change the plaintext password to a prompt. Luckily, I found [this guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx), which I intend to incorporate. So, I delete the existing $Password and enter this in its place:

```
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
```

And put this additional code in the foreach area, in place of the $MySecureCreds thing:

```
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword
```

I'd also like to wrap the try command around a ping test/result. Apparently I can do that with the following command and then get rid of the try/catch there. And then write-warning the else command.

```
if((Test-Connection -TargetName $($Computer.IPAddress) -Quiet -Count 1) -ne $null)
```

I'm also wondering if maybe I should include a validation for the credentials, in the event it doesn't work. I found [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Verify-the-Local-User-1e365545/) but am wondering if I need to create the object or if I can somehow just strip some of that down and including it in the foreach part.

Lastly, I'm wondering if I should have it generate one csv at the end or put it in the foreach section. Not having to work with a bunch of individual files is nice but waiting for it to process 200 IP addresses isn't that fun.

Comment: Why not manage updates using a tool like WSUS?

Comment: They're not in SCCM or on the domain. They're on the network but they each have local logins and are on workgroup computers. And they each have varying internet connections. There's also not a dedicated server or the resources for one.

Comment: IMO it would likely be cheaper in the long run to install a Windows Server (rather than trying to script a solution). You don't have to have a domain to use WSUS.

Comment: These are being upgraded in the future. This is just temporary until the funding gets approved and the work gets done to replace these machines. I'm not asking for any kind of commentary or extraneous details that do not pertain to the code in question. If I was needing advice about what to do with these machines, I would have **asked for it**.